# Время и дата определяются не правильно

Tags: java, android, дата, время, чат

Делаю чат с помощью Firebase. Возникла проблема с датой и временем. В сообщениях некоторых пользователей дата и время определяются неверно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При отправке сообщения получаю дату и время с помощью new Date().getTime();
В адаптере преобразую время сообщения в нормальное с помощью DateFormat.format("dd.MM(HH:mm)",model.getMessageTime());
Может я что-то не так делаю? В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно у того пользователя стоит неправильное время на устройстве?

Comment: Скорее часовой пояс задан неверно

Comment: Проблема не у одного пользователя. Не думаю, что у нескольких проблема со временем

Comment: Часовой пояс влияет на Timestamp?

Comment: Мне кажется это вам может помочь:
http://qaru.site/questions/18975/is-javasqltimestamp-timezone-specific

Comment: @SINON, если время задано правильно, а пояс нет, то timestamp будет не правильным.

Comment: @woesss, можно это как-то исправить? Получать какое-то единое время для всех пользователей, чтобы оно не зависело от времени на устройстве или часового пояса?

Comment: @SINON   
вот тут есть:    
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific/14070771#14070771

Comment: @SINON, запись timestamp'а сообщения лучше бы делегировать серверу - тогда он не будет зависеть от настроек устройства. Но на устройстве в любом случае придётся сверять его currentTimeMillis c сервером времени и делать коррекцию, с учётом разницы, при выводе сообщения.